# Остановить все audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-audio

Как можно остановить все теги `<audio>` на странице?
 Пробовал так :

```
 obj = $('audio');
 obj.pause();
```

и нечего.

Comment: наверное, так вы находите первый объект с именем `audio`. Там есть метод, который возвращает массив объектов по имени?

Comment: там это где? это на jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы хотите использовать `pause()` то нужно делать примерно так:

```
$('audio').each(function(){
    this.pause();
})
```

Дело в том, что этот метод нужно применять отдельно к каждому элементу `DOM` (не к объекту `jQuery`). 
Ну а вообще, я Вам написал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470517/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-audio-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5), как лучше сделать это используя `jQuery`.