# Остановить <audio> на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-audio

Как можно остановить все теги  на странице?

Comment: сами что-то пишите или готовый проигрыватель ?
может это поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function

Comment: Сам, так бы не спрашивал :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$("audio").trigger('pause');
```